# Change Jquery Validation Rules according to user choice

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have the following situation: If the user clicks the save button must apply a rule, if click in publish button the rule is other.

Currently is not applying any.

```
saveBtn.on('click', function(){
    $('form').validate(publish_rules);
});

publishBtn.on('click', function(){
    $('form').validate(save_continue_rules);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call the `.validate()` method multiple times to change rules.  It's only used for *initializing* the plugin one time.

Instead, the developer has provided [the `.rules()` methods](http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/) for dynamically adding and removing rules.

```
$('#myform').validate({ // initialize plugin
    // rules & options
});

saveBtn.on('click', function() {
    $('#myfield').rules('add', {
        required: true
    });
});

publishBtn.on('click', function(){
     $('#myfield').rules('remove', 'required');
});
```

Then if you need to programmatically trigger validation within your `click` handlers, you would call [the `.valid()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid)...

```
$('#myform').valid();  // triggers validation of entire form

$('#myfield').valid();  // triggers validation of a field
```